# TypeError: Network request failed only on POST method

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, fetch

I am trying to fetch POST in React Native for a Node server that I made myself. When I make a **POST** attempt, it returns **"[TypeError: Network request failed]"**, but when I make a **GET** attempt it executes it. I already tested it on PostMan and everything happens correctly. I'm using AVD (Android Emulator)

**REACT NATIVE:**

```
    _updateInfos = () => {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    myHeaders.append("x-access-token", this.props.cookie);

    const body = new FormData();

    body.append("postid", this.state.shop.id);
    body.append("whatsapp", this.state.whatsapp);
    body.append("telefone", this.state.telefone);

    var links = [{
        network: {
            Instagram: {
                url: "https://instagram.com/" + this.state.instagram + "/",
            },
            Facebook: {
                url: "https://facebook.com/" + this.state.facebook + "/",
            }
        }
    }]

    var toApi = Serialize.serialize(links);

    body.append("links", toApi);

    var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: body,
    redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("http://api.parquedasfeiras.online/api/uploads", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

**NODEJS:**

```
app.post('/api/updateinfos', function (req, res) {
  var postId = req.body.postid;

  var whatapp = req.body.whatsapp;
  var telefone = req.body.telefone;

  var links = req.body.links;

  console.log(postId);
  console.log(whatapp);
  console.log(telefone);
  console.log(links);

  res.send("hey")
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my lack of attention, I ended up going the wrong body, right way:

```
     const body = new URLSearchParams ();
     body.append ("postid", this.state.shop.id);
     body.append ("whatsapp", this.state.whatsapp);
     body.append ("phone", this.state.phone);
```